# Pass dato between Actions - Symfony 2.6

Tags: forms, symfony, view

well I have some problems to pass data between actions...

I have a actions that have a form, this form only have 2 element, a text area and a radiobutton.

well, I need pass the text and choice to other action and show this text and this choice... I try whit manual of symfony but I don't see how to make...

Thanks !

Comment: Have you created your own form class?  Its straight forward from the book - read the section on creating a form, rendering it, and handling form submissions at [symfony2 form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).  If you have problems, post your form code and the controller.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was be that in the condicion about is valid I don't redirect correctly... but now run ! thanks... :)